# Save image to a specific folder using cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to save an image captured using cordova camera plugin to a specific directory for windows 8.1 application. But I am not able to find an exact solution for this. I have gone through many questions and forums, no luck.

Here is a sample code I have tried.

```
onTakePhoto: function () {
                navigator.camera.getPicture(this.onPhotoSuccess, this.onPhotoFail, {
                    quality: 100,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
                });
            },

            //Callback function if onTakePhoto action is success.
            onPhotoSuccess: function (oImageURI) {
                console.log("In Success " + oImageURI);
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(oImageURI, this.handlePicSave, this.onPhotoFail); 
            },

            //Callback function if onTakePhoto action fails
            onPhotoFail: function (oError) {
                console.log("In Fail " + oError);
            },

            //Handle pic save
            handlePicSave: function(oEntry) {
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSys) {
                    fileSys.root.getDirectory("MyPhotos", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (directory) {
                        oEntry.moveTo(directory, "WO_2.jpg", that.successMove, that.onPhotoFail);
                   }, that.onPhotoFail);
                },
                    that.onPhotoFail);

            },
```

The above code works fine and saves the image to the app root folder i.e C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Packages\App_name\LocalState\MyPhotos\WO_2.jpg

But I need to store directly to C drive like.. C:\MyPhotos\WO_2.jpg

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? Is it possible to save files to C or and drive using this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check [cordova file plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file), It allows to access differents folders and read / write. I do not use it for camera purposes, but I used it for saving files in diferent projects and works fine.

Comment: True, however keep in mind that the Windows Phone 7 and 8 platforms do not support `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffe`r nor `FileWriter.write(blob)`.

Comment: @Del I am already using the File plugin in the handlePicSave method. But tat is creating a file in the root directory. I am not able to store in C drive. I mite be missing something here.

Comment: Probably a way to play with File plugin outside the root directory.

Comment: With this plugin, you can access to the directories indicated under the "Android File System Layout", in the table. Check if you can access to the path that you want, and use the correct variable. If it does not appears, then you can't access to that directory